# Why is Lagrangian important?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In physics Lagrangian is a formulation for dynamic systems and we can deduce equation of motion using the Lagrange equation. But, mathematicaly,  does lagrangian system means something? Which are the application of this? Is it linked somehow with variational formulations?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_system), in fact, does not clarify anything.

Comment: In many (in fact, probably most) physical situations, this method is far superior to using F = ma. See for example chapter 6 in http://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/winter2008/physics110b/lectures.html or http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/chap6.pdf

Comment: @cgiovanardi first link is already dead but thanks for the second link. Very readable.